# cardano-node preprod testnet sync stuck in nix develop, possible headerError

Tags: cardano-node, nix, preprod

Supposed to run testnet node in `nix develop`.

`which cardano-node` outputs `/nix/store/y29rzxcr6vswgc5nhmind0cjbkqxi414-cardano-node-exe-cardano-node-1.35.3/bin/cardano-node`

seems to be a HeaderError with this command `cardano-node run --topology configs/testnet-topology.json --database-path db --socket-path node.socket --config configs/testnet-config.json`

The configs I got is from [here](https://hydra.iohk.io/build/8111119/download/1)

This is the log of the node.

```
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:41.82 UTC] TracePromoteColdPeers 50 0 (fromList [3.72.231.105:30000])
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:158][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:41.82 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:158][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:41.99 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 1})
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:159][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TrConnectionHandler (ConnectionId {localAddress = 192.168.1.129:42787, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}) (TrHandshakeSuccess NodeToNodeV_10 (NodeToNodeVersionData {networkMagic = NetworkMagic {unNetworkMagic = 1}, diffusionMode = InitiatorAndResponderDiffusionMode}))
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:158][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 1, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 1})
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionActions:Info:158][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] PeerStatusChanged (ColdToWarm (Just 192.168.1.129:42787) 3.72.231.105:30000)
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TracePromoteColdDone 50 1 3.72.231.105:30000
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionCounters:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] PeerSelectionCounters {coldPeers = 0, warmPeers = 1, hotPeers = 0}
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TracePromoteWarmPeers 2 0 (fromList [3.72.231.105:30000])
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:60][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TrInboundGovernorCounters (InboundGovernorCounters {coldPeersRemote = 0, idlePeersRemote = 1, warmPeersRemote = 0, hotPeersRemote = 0})
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionActions:Info:164][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] PeerStatusChanged (WarmToHot (ConnectionId {localAddress = 192.168.1.129:42787, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}))
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] TracePromoteWarmDone 2 1 3.72.231.105:30000
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionCounters:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.37 UTC] PeerSelectionCounters {coldPeers = 0, warmPeers = 0, hotPeers = 1}
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionActions:Info:162][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] PeerStatusChanged (HotToCold (ConnectionId {localAddress = 192.168.1.129:42787, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}))
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelection:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] TraceDemoteAsynchronous (fromList [(3.72.231.105:30000,PeerCold)])
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.PeerSelectionCounters:Info:56][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] PeerSelectionCounters {coldPeers = 1, warmPeers = 0, hotPeers = 0}
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.InboundGovernor:Info:60][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] TrMuxErrored (ConnectionId {localAddress = 192.168.1.129:42787, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}) (HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 86400, blockPointHash = c971bfb21d2732457f9febf79d9b02b20b9a3bef12c561a78b818bcb8b35a574})) (HeaderProtocolError (HardForkValidationErrFromEra S (Z (WrapValidationErr {unwrapValidationErr = ChainTransitionError [OverlayFailure (VRFKeyBadNonce (Nonce "81e47a19e6b29b0a65b9591762ce5143ed30d0261e5d24a3201752506b20f15c") (SlotNo 86400) (Nonce "90c8bae45d3cb34ef25d84171a74f6e8a4a8f4615fbe289d5a1b21eb6896ac0b") (CertifiedVRF {certifiedOutput = OutputVRF {getOutputVRFBytes = "n\240\190\146\147\245\163\a\ETX{`\183%.\174\153\187\EOT]X\165!\213\186|\141:\161))*\SOH*\147\145\238\255\248\132?5X\179Re\236C%\SOH\178F\136\162\224\162\EMd\252q\207i\194]\174"}, certifiedProof = CertPraosVRF "=C\193CW\205\131\176\249A\248\199\231\165s\252\&6\ESC\135\STX\191\238!\ESC\215\173\177\165\159\149v\254\ESC\209\RS?\163+Z\152.{$n\CAN\ENQ\139\t\159\DC4sb\201\193\138\204C\225\228\232\181\183\198`\234>\217\172[z~\192\254\181\156\207\182G)\EOT"})),OverlayFailure (OcertFailure (InvalidKesSignatureOCERT 1 0 1 "Verification failed"))]})))) (Tip (SlotNo 79922) 3785f8aee4d2369be761572b877358eeb9351404354b97ef965240bdbd602378 (BlockNo 43)) (Tip (SlotNo 11802321) 666c3386466185c49d725d6a1e4ff65e8b26933c4236126cb4182c794d224577 (BlockNo 231597)))
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:159][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] TrConnectionHandler (ConnectionId {localAddress = 192.168.1.129:42787, remoteAddress = 3.72.231.105:30000}) (TrError OutboundError (HeaderError (At (Block {blockPointSlot = SlotNo 86400, blockPointHash = c971bfb21d2732457f9febf79d9b02b20b9a3bef12c561a78b818bcb8b35a574})) (HeaderProtocolError (HardForkValidationErrFromEra S (Z (WrapValidationErr {unwrapValidationErr = ChainTransitionError [OverlayFailure (VRFKeyBadNonce (Nonce "81e47a19e6b29b0a65b9591762ce5143ed30d0261e5d24a3201752506b20f15c") (SlotNo 86400) (Nonce "90c8bae45d3cb34ef25d84171a74f6e8a4a8f4615fbe289d5a1b21eb6896ac0b") (CertifiedVRF {certifiedOutput = OutputVRF {getOutputVRFBytes = "n\240\190\146\147\245\163\a\ETX{`\183%.\174\153\187\EOT]X\165!\213\186|\141:\161))*\SOH*\147\145\238\255\248\132?5X\179Re\236C%\SOH\178F\136\162\224\162\EMd\252q\207i\194]\174"}, certifiedProof = CertPraosVRF "=C\193CW\205\131\176\249A\248\199\231\165s\252\&6\ESC\135\STX\191\238!\ESC\215\173\177\165\159\149v\254\ESC\209\RS?\163+Z\152.{$n\CAN\ENQ\139\t\159\DC4sb\201\193\138\204C\225\228\232\181\183\198`\234>\217\172[z~\192\254\181\156\207\182G)\EOT"})),OverlayFailure (OcertFailure (InvalidKesSignatureOCERT 1 0 1 "Verification failed"))]})))) (Tip (SlotNo 79922) 3785f8aee4d2369be761572b877358eeb9351404354b97ef965240bdbd602378 (BlockNo 43)) (Tip (SlotNo 11802321) 666c3386466185c49d725d6a1e4ff65e8b26933c4236126cb4182c794d224577 (BlockNo 231597))) ShutdownPeer)
[34m[hud-PS:cardano.node.ConnectionManager:Info:159][0m [2022-11-03 14:25:42.94 UTC] TrConnectionManagerCounters (ConnectionManagerCounters {fullDuplexConns = 0, duplexConns = 0, unidirectionalConns = 0, inboundConns = 0, outboundConns = 0})
```

and query-tip shows it is stuck at:

```
{
    "block": 43,
    "epoch": 3,
    "era": "Byron",
    "hash": "3785f8aee4d2369be761572b877358eeb9351404354b97ef965240bdbd602378",
    "slot": 79922,
    "syncProgress": "11.89"
}
```

How do I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 1):

Use config files from https://book.world.dev.cardano.org/environments.html for Pre-Production Testnet